# How to type in a particular language in android

Tags: android, localization

i want to make an app that shows everything in hebrew language . Now i know how to do it for pre known texts like Toolbar text , and all others texts on an app like about , settings etc . I just create a folder named values-he and right save hebrew words inside it . But the hard part is to have the user be able to type in hebrew language and showing it in my editText . Can anyone tell me how do i achieve this. Any tutorial any libraries i can use or any other hint.

Answer (score 1):

For type in Hebrew, you just have to change the keyboard language.

If you use google keyboard [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6102154?hl=en) is a help page.

Comment: Ok thanks , but still i can't have the user go to those settings and change all that can't i change the keyboard programatically?

Comment: You can't change programatically [1], but you can ask the user to change and display the input method picker [2].
[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/ZAvbAKU8Gbg/dFtEnxe4aQUJ
[2] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#showInputMethodPicker()

Comment: Ok i'll look in to it . But we can do so many things in applications why can't we do such a basic task?
p.s thanks :)